# send name to Outlook new contact from command line

Tags: command-line, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, shortcuts, contacts

i have a working [Windows shortcut, which opens a new contact form in Outlook 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/command-line-switches-for-outlook-2010-HP010354956.aspx) `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE" /recycle /c ipm.contact`

*But i would like to additionally pass in a first name and last name, which would then populate the form.*

- i tried `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE" /recycle /c ipm.contact John Doe` but that does not work.

Is it possible ?

p.s. My final solution would be making use of [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/) rather than `cmd.exe`, the important thing is to make it work work from command-line though.